# Excel Sum(Indirect))

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code that has the user type in how many stages are needed and then from there, the stages are copied from a "stage1" worksheet. On another sheet I am trying to create a sum(indirect)) formula to look up the materials number and then correspond to the "amt to order" column. I created this formula:

> = SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage1!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage1!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage2!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage2!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage3!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5 ,INDIRECT("Stage3!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage4!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5 ,INDIRECT("Stage4!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage5!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5 ,INDIRECT("Stage5!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage6!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5 ,INDIRECT("Stage6!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage7!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage7!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage8!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage8!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage9!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage9!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage10!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage10!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage11!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage11!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage12!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage12!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage13!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage13!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage14!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage14!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage15!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage15!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage16!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage16!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage17!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage17!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage18!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage18!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage19!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage19!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage20!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage20!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage21!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage21!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage22!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage22!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage23!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage23!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage24!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage24!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage25!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage25!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage26!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage26!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage27!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage27!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage28!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage28!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage29!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage29!$E$6:$E$18")) +SUMIF(INDIRECT("Stage30!$C$6:$C$18"), $A5, INDIRECT("Stage30!$E$6:$E$18"))

But when I used it and had the user only input 9 stages then the #REF! error came back. Any help would be great! I've been stuck for a while.

Thank you!

Comment: Range references like `INDIRECT("Stage1!$C$6:$C$18")` can just as easily be written as `Stage1!$C$6:$C$18`. Your use of INDIRECT seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Jeeped beat me to it... Always try to avoid `INDIRECT()` as much as you can, it's volatile (_recalculates any time a change is made __anywhere__ in your workbook_) so can quickly ramp up the resources your file uses.

Answer (score 3):

I think I see what you are trying to do. You want the INDIRECT to apply what is essentially the same SUMIF to multiple worksheets. Here is an example using a reduced number of worksheets.

I created 4 identical worksheets, Stage1, Stage2, Stage3 and Stage4, with the following data.

[image]

Then in Sheet1 (where I plan to use the formula) I made a list of those identical worksheets in F2:F5. In A5 I used a value for the criteria then in B5 I used this formula.

```
'standard formula with known number of worksheets
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(TEXT(F$2:F$5, "'@'!")&"C6:C18"),$A5,INDIRECT(TEXT(F$2:F$5, "'@'!")&"E6:E18")))
'array formula for unknown number of worksheets
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT(TEXT(F$2:F$5, "'@'!")&"C6:C18"),$A5,INDIRECT(TEXT(F$2:F$5, "'@'!")&"E6:E18")), 0))
```

In the sample image below, you can see that the formula is picking up the SUMIF subtotals from each worksheet and producing a total.

The second formula is there in case you do not want to modify your worksheet list. If a worksheet cannot be found, it returns zero for that name in the list, not a #REF! error.

Note that the second formula is an array formula and must be finished with ctr+shift+enter, not just enter.

[image]

With the second array formula and a non-existent worksheet name in the list.

[image]

Now you should be able to significantly reduce your formula by creating a list of the worksheets to be subtotaled. and adjusting the above formula to suit.

You can test the worksheet names in your list by putting this formula in Sheet1!G2 and filling down.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(INDIRECT(TEXT(F2, "'@'!")&"A1")))
```

TRUE means the worksheet exists in the workbook, FALSE means you fouled up somewhere.

Comment: I think that it took me longer to review the Post and your Answer than it took for you write your Answer.  +1 ∞